# django context processing with condition

Tags: django, render

I have django context where I want to put values conditionally.How can I do that ?

I tried as per below, but not working as needed:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = Context()
        context['p_list1'] = p_list1
        context['p_list2'] = p_list2
        context['p_list3'] = p_list3
```

Here is the context part where I want to put p_list1 values after the "," . When I write inside the context part it's working but I can't do that because I will put there or not  depending on calculation i will do prior.

```
context = {
            'instance': fp0,
            'user': user,
        }
        return render(request, 'ts_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*put `p_list1` values after the `,`*"? Here `p_list1` is not defined in the head, and furthermore there is no comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to use basic Python data structures such as a `dict`? My suspicion is that all you need is something as simple as:

```
context = {
    'instance': fp0,
    'user': user,
}
if complex_calculation:
    context['p_list1'] = p_list1
    # ...
return render(request, 'ts_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: This is working but for future reference I need to put here for others that it will not work if the context=  is below of the if calculation: part  which I was trying to do and was not working.